# Drupal 8 - File Entity Browser installation

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I am looking for some help with setting up [File Entity Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_browser).  I am new to Drupal but have been a developer for years. I followed the "instructions" as best I could: I installed the Entity Browser module, the DropZone module, and did the bower thing (though I am not certain what "install from the file_browser directory" means). All the modules are enabled. What additional steps do I take to get the drag/drop screen to show? What additional information can I provide?

Answer (score 0):

[Folder stucture in Drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84811/what-are-all-the-directories-for-in-the-new-drupal-8-structure) has changed. Libraries are now in `/libraries`

You should have this folder structure:

`/modules/entity_browser
/modules/file_browser
/modules/dropzonejs
/libraries/dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.js`

You should then `cd` into `/modules/file_browser` in shell and run `bower install`

Once everything is in place you can test if it's working by following [this guide](https://drupal-media.gitbooks.io/drupal8-guide/content/modules/file_browser/index.html)